# Marshal a fixed length array to pointers from C++ to C# inside structure

Tags: c#, marshalling

I want to marshal some struct, which contains field like `const void *data[3]` in C++ to something like `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3)] IntPtr[] data`, but Marshaling failed with exception.

In the same time if I just create 3 separate field like `IntPtr data0, data1, data2`, marshaling start working correctly. But this looks ugly. Is there a way to write it in a single field?

Please, help me. This issue is driving me crazy.

**EDIT**
Exception was `'Method's type signature is not PInvoke compatible`

Comment: What was the exception?

Comment: Edited my question @WaiHaLee